# How to add particular attribute of product in shop as well as home page

Tags: customization

How to add particular attribute of product in shop as well as in homepage

Comment: You'll have to provide is with some code samples and/or screenhots of how other attributes are used, and let us know which plugins you are using for the products/shop, since those are not native to WordPress.

Comment: We are using woocommerce. Here we are using three attributes for each product: writer, publisher, binding. We want that the 'writer' attribute value will be displayed just below to the product's name in home as well as shop page.

Comment: You can see here: thinkerslane.com